# Spring boot - JVM arguments in .conf file not working

Tags: java, spring, jvm

guys !
I've tried several method to start spring boot application with JVM arguments, but without success.
I want to start the APP with enabled GC collection logging, so i've tried to put in myprogram.conf (my jar is myprogram.jar) in the same directory:

```
 JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:/opt/app/gc.log
```

But the APP started without arguments. I tried with simple

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512M
```

But still the app start without any arguments.
What could be the reasons for this ?

Best regards.

Comment: how do you ignite JVM ?

Comment: java -jar myprogram.jar

Comment: then just pass it via `java -Xmx512M -jar myprogram.jar`

Comment: But this is not the case.. i want to use Spring boot in production, which will start from linux services (service start myprogram.jar) so i want to use properties files or .conf file.

Comment: What you mean by " I tried with simple ..."? What exactly have you tried? Show us the command or the script that you used.